# Is it possible to pass the onClick function of reactbootstrap table inside of Component using ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a question regarding declaring handler, is it possible to call the onclick function inside of parent component? because the error shows

> Cannot read property 'DeleteUser' of undefined.

So outside of extends Component, I have const column and I have formatter function that look like this.

```
formatter: (cellContent, row) => {
    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
    <button className="btn btn-primary
     form-control btn-small" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" value={row.id}><i class="far fa-edit" style={{fontSize:12}}></i></button> &nbsp;&nbsp;
     <button className="btn btn-danger
     form-control btn-small" onClick={this.DeleteUser} value={row.id}><i class="fas fa-trash-alt" style={{fontSize:12}}></i></button>
    </div>         
}
```

Inside my Component, I have this.

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        list_user:[],
    }

    this.DeleteUser = this.DeleteUser.bind(this);
}

DeleteUser() {
    alert('george'); 
}
```

So now when I refresh my page error shows Undefined DeleteUser.

Comment: You can make the use of arrow functions so you wont have to bind to the wrong thing inside the constructor. Make your function like this: DeleteUSer () => { alert('george') }

Comment: can you give example @manAbl

Comment: that function is wrong also. so when i click it shows this . Cannot read property 'DeleteUser' of undefined

Comment: Where is `formatter`, and how are you calling it?

Comment: yeah that may be the problem. Formatter is bind to the wrong this @DevGe

Comment: @Andy hi, formatter declared outside of class component. i just passing the column variable inside of bootstraptable